# Delphi CGI (on IIS) with TWebModule, how handle TThread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, iis, cgi

In a CGI made with `TWebModule` i want, on request, perform a background long operation, but send an instantaneous response:

```
procedure TMyWebModule.MyAction(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
   aMyThread : TMyThread;
begin
    Handled := true;
    aMyThread := TMyThread.Create;
    Response.Content := 'request is processing...';
end;
```

`TMyThread` is

```
type
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
  end;

implementation


constructor TMyThread.Create;
begin
 inherited Create(false);

 Self.FreeOnTerminate := true;
end;


procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  WriteLog('START');
  try
    Sleep(20000);
  finally
      WriteLog('END');
  end;
end;
```

The CGI seem kill the thread on server response, because i found `START` but not `END`.
IIS on response seem close the connection and send SIGTERM to the CGI process, that kills the threads.

How i can handle thread on CGI?

Comment: Perform the long running operation in a different process asynchronously: pass the required data over to a background worker service (for example by HTTP or by using some message queue, or by storing it in a database tabel) and let the worker service do it.

Comment: p.s. nice introduction to asynchronous processing for web aplications: ["Doppler: it's made of messages"](https://www.slideshare.net/carsonified/dopplr-its-made-of-messages-matt-biddulph-presentation) by Matt Biddulph

Comment: I solved this problem in http://yoy.be/xxm by using a stub CGI handler that opens [a pipe to/from a dedicated process](https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm/blob/master/Delphi/cgi/xxmCGI.dpr#L29) that handles the request/response _and keeps running in the background_. I very strongly advise to check out SCGI or ISAPI, as it performs better than CGI. (And for which xxm also has handlers...)